# jQuery class selector and click event, am i missing something?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I'm quite new to jQuery and its selectors.

I've many links used to switch language. Languages are stored in `languages` variable, and the current language index (called `lang`) is stored in `document`. When i click on one single link it changes correctly (cycle through the array), but **any other links remain unchanged**. Why? `$('.lang')` selector is supposed to select all my links...

```
var languages = ['en', 'sl', 'at', 'de'];
$(document).data('lang', 0); // Just for the first page load

$('.lang').text(languages[($(document).data('lang'))])
    .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)'); // Set href and text

$('.lang').click(function() {
    // Set link text to the current language and increment counter
    $(this).text(languages[(($(document).data('lang') + 1) % languages.length)]);
    $(document).data('lang', $(document).data('lang') + 1)
});

<a class="lang"></a>
<a class="lang"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in your click function you referring to `this`, ie only the current link that has been clicked you need

```
$('.lang').click(function() {
    // Set link text to the current language and increment counter
    $('.lang').text(languages[(($(document).data('lang') + 1) % languages.length)]);
    $(document).data('lang', $(document).data('lang') + 1)
});
```

as shown in this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WhtqR/

You are correct in that `$('.lang')` will select all of your links with that class. In your code it applies the click function to each of the links handlers. But the function that gets executed on click needed that tag rather than `this`.